# Magento2 : How to add attribute options values into dropdown attribute programmatically

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, attribute-options

Need way to add options to already created **Color** attribute.

Comment: Ref: https://webkul.com/blog/programmatically-add-options-attribute-magento2/

Comment: i have tried using this way but not working

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201226/create-product-attribute-of-type-multiselect-or-dropdown-select-create-option

Comment: let me know whether you would like to associate option values using csv?

Comment: Hello @Sourav, any solution worked for you ?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa

yes using csv

Comment: hello @Sourav have u tried my solution please let me know if u facing any issue?

Answer (score 4):

Please follow below steps

1.Create **csv** with color and attribute values as shown below
& keep your csv at **M2root/scripts/colorvalues.csv**

[image]

2. Create **colors.php** at Magento 2 root directory and paste below code & 
   execute script using **command line**

> **php colors.php**

```
 <?php

    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $entityType = 'catalog_product';
    $directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
    $path  =  $directory->getRoot().'/scripts/';
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
    $eavSetup = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $stores = $storeManager->getStores();
    $storeArray[0] = "All Store Views";
    foreach ($stores  as $store) 
    {
       $storeArray[$store->getId()] = $store->getName();
    }

    $fname = 'colorvalues.csv';

    $file = fopen($path.$fname, "r");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        foreach((array)$data[0] as $attributeCode)
        {
        $option = array();
        $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute($entityType, $attributeCode);
        $option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getAttributeId();
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        if($data[1])
        {
        foreach((array)$data[1] as $key => $value)
        {
            $str = '"'.$value.'"';
            $option['value'][$str][0]=str_replace('"','', $str);
            foreach($storeArray as $storeKey => $store) 
            {
              $option['value'][$str][$storeKey] = str_replace('"','', $str);
            }   

        }

        $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);


        }
        }
    }
        fclose($file);

    echo "Attribute option values has been associated to brand attribute SUCCESSFULLY";
```

3. do Re index from command line
   **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

**Imp Note:** Please try in your default magento2 in local system first and test properly.

Please let me know still facing any issue?

Comment: ok i try and let you know

Comment: Can confirm that this still works in 2.4.4. Thanks so much. All scripts now need to go into /pub so I had to change the references. You don't know how much time you've just saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy to the understandable script here.

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require 'app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

attributeValue::addValuesforAttribute('colorAttribute');

class attributeValue{

    public static function addValuesforAttribute($attributeCode)
    {
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $fileCsv = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\File\Csv');
       $attributeFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory');
       $eavFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AttributeFactory');
        $option = array();
        $eavFactory = $eavFactory->create()->load($attributeCode,"attribute_code");
        $option['attribute_id'] = $eavFactory->getAttributeId();
        $values = "attributeValue.csv";
        $csvData = $fileCsv->getData($values);
        foreach ($csvData as $row => $data) {
                $color = $data[0];
                $option['value'][$color][] =  $color;
    }
        $eavSetup = $attributeFactory->create();
        $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);
        echo " \n Options are ";
        print_r($option);
        echo " Succesfull add Options for Attribute ".$attributeCode;
    }
}
```

CSV color name formate is
[image]

Comment: Thanks this helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

**Add Attributte Option Like This :-**

```
public function __construct(
         \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
         \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AttributeFactory $eavAttribute
   ){
     $this->_eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
     $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
     $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
   }

public function yourFunction()
{
           $attributeId = $this->_eavAttribute->create()->load('color','attribute_code');
           $option = [enter_option_here];
           $allStores = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
           $option['attribute_id'] = $attributeId->getAttributeId();
           foreach($option as $key=>$value){
                $option['value'][$value][0]=$value;
                    foreach($allStores as $store){
                        $option['value'][$value][$store->getId()] = $value;
                    }
                }
                $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create();
                $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);}
}
```

**Reference Link :-**

[Import Attribute Options Programmatically](https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-attribute-options-magento-2-programmatically/)

Comment: this is for magento 1 way  i have already tried

Comment: this used in magento 2 also i used this in my module

Comment: I used same link 
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-attribute-options-magento-2-programmatically/

but in backend there is not any options showing

Comment: I want to update options values from csv file & using code in file that is at root of magento

Comment: https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-attribute-options-magento-2-programmatically/

I use same code but in admin new values uploaded

Comment: using custom script ?

Comment: Yes i am using code in file location at root & picking values from csv

Comment: code not working in magento 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I've modified @Nagaraju Kasa's solution to allow the script to work with 2.4.4 (not tested higher than that, but it should be OK).

- Since executable scripts need to be within the `/pub` dir, I've changed the require line
- I've also added a check in there to not add the option if it exists already. Magento will just add them anyway and then you're in for a fun day deleting duplicates in the attributes page! This should now mean you don't need to do that :)

Place your csv file in `pub/add_opts/csv`.

The CSV file hasn't changed from the original answer, it just needs to be [attribute_code],[new_option], so:

```
color,red
color,blue
color,seafoam green
```

Place this file in `pub/add_opts` (name this directory whatever)

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require '../../app/bootstrap.php';

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $entityType = 'catalog_product';
    $directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
    $path  =  $directory->getRoot().'/scripts/';
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
    $eavSetup = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $stores = $storeManager->getStores();
    $storeArray[0] = "All Store Views";
    foreach ($stores  as $store) 
    {
       $storeArray[$store->getId()] = $store->getName();
    }


    $fname = 'csv/options.csv';

    $file = fopen($fname, "r");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        foreach((array)$data[0] as $attributeCode)
        {
            $option = array();
            $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute($entityType, $attributeCode);
            $option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getAttributeId();
            $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
            echo "<h2>" . $attributeCode . "</h2><Br />";

            // Unquote to see dump of current options
            //echo "<pre>" . print_r($options, true) . "</pre>";
            if($data[1])
            {
            foreach((array)$data[1] as $key => $value)
            {
                $str = '"'.$value.'"';
                
                if(in_array($value, array_column($options, 'label'))){
                    echo "<h4 style='color:#ff0000;'>" . $value . "</h4><br />";
                    echo "<p style='color:#ff0000;'>$value already exists in options</p>";
                }else{
                    echo "<p>Adding $value to options</p>";
                    $option['value'][$str][0]=str_replace('"','', $str);

                    foreach($storeArray as $storeKey => $store) 
                    {
                        $option['value'][$str][$storeKey] = str_replace('"','', $str);
                    }
                }

            }

            $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);
            echo "<hr />";

            }
        }
    }
        fclose($file);
```